# Infinite Scroll Pagination Package refreshes the entire page instead of appending results

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages

I have incorporated the [infinite_scroll_pagination package](https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination) into my Flutter app. While the implementation mostly works as expected, I have a problem?

My app has a search bar at the top followed by a list of cards. The cards are paginated and loaded in chunks of 10. The expected behavior is that, as I scroll, each subsequent page of results should append to the bottom of the existing list.

The problem arises when a new page is fetched. Instead of the new results appending seamlessly to the bottom of the current list, a spinning loading indicator appears in the center of the screen, and the entire page seems to refresh. This forces the user to start scrolling from the top again. However, if the user does scroll down, the next results have indeed been loaded correctly.

The primary issue is: Why is the entire page refreshing, and how can I make it so that new results simply append at the bottom without this full-page refresh and also i notice it will reload the same results over if it reaches the end of my searched query?

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

**Initialization of the PagingController and related variables:**

```
final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
final PagingController<int, ItemData> _pagingController =
    PagingController(firstPageKey: 0);
static const int _pageSize = 10;
```

**Initialization and the listener setup in initState:**

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _pagingController.addPageRequestListener((pageKey) {
    _fetchPage(pageKey);
  });

  _controller.addListener(() {
    if (_debounce?.isActive ?? false) _debounce?.cancel();
    _debounce = Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 300), () {
      _fetchPage(0);
    });
  });
  ...
}
```

**The _fetchPage function which handles data fetching and appending pages:**

```
Future<void> _fetchPage(int pageKey) async {
  print('Fetching page with key: $pageKey');
  if (pageKey == 0) {
    _pagingController.itemList = [];
  }
  int sectionNumber = pageKey ~/ _pageSize;
  print('Loading section $sectionNumber');

  try {
    final newItems = await Provider.of<ItemDataModel>(context, listen: false)
        .fetchItemData(_controller.text, pageKey: pageKey, filters: filters);
    ...
    if (isLastPage) {
      _pagingController.appendLastPage(newItems);
    } else {
      final nextPageKey = pageKey + newItems.length;
      _pagingController.appendPage(newItems, nextPageKey);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    _pagingController.error = error;
  }
}
```

**The widget structure that includes the PagedSliverList:**

```
else if (_controller.text.trim().isNotEmpty)
  PagedSliverList<int, ItemData>(
    pagingController: _pagingController,
    builderDelegate: PagedChildBuilderDelegate<ItemData>(
      itemBuilder: (context, item, index) => InkWell(
        onTap: () => _navigateToItemDetail(context, item),
        child: ItemCard(itemData: item),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```